# AWS Lambda is not triggering when a git tag is pushed in a CodeCommit repository

Tags: git, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I'm having the next issue:

I have a CI/CD process with the following AWS stack:

- Someone pushes a change into a CodeCommit repository
- A Lambda function is triggered
- A CodeBuild process runs to build my repository

The process works fine when a change is pushed in any branch (master and develop) but is not working if a git tag is pushed. So:

`git push origin develop` -> the Lambda function triggers and CodeBuild works fine

`git push origin master` -> the Lambda function triggers and CodeBuild works fine

`git tag 1.0.0`  `git push --tags` -> Nothing happen. The Lambda function is not triggering

The config for Lambda function is the following:

```
Branches: develop, master
Custom data: my-codebuild-project
Events: createReference, updateReference
Repository name: my-codecommit-repo
Service principal: codecommit.amazonaws.com
Statement ID: lambda-5b3c4bd9-921d-4ee7-9177-a7b1a1f8132c
Trigger name: my-lambda-trigger
```

Any ideas?

From the official AWS doc:
You can create triggers for events you specify, such as when a commit is pushed to a repository. Event types include:

- all: for all events in the specified repository and branches.
- updateReference: for when commits are pushed to the specified repository and branches.
- createReference: for when a new branch or tag is created in the specified repository.
- deleteReference: for when a branch or tag is deleted in the specified repository.

So in theory, when i push a tag, the trigger must work if the event is configured by createReference.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i figured it out.

I had to set the setting Branches to “All Branches” instead of “Master” and “Develop”. For some reason pushing a tag only triggers the function if that setting is that way.